# access variable in let command

Tags: tikz-pgf, letters

I would like to access the x1 variable from let command as below:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (P) at (0,0) {Hello};
\path let \p1=($(P.east)-(P.west)$) in 
     node[draw=red,anchor=west,text width=\textwidth-\x1] (Q) at (P.east) {World};
\message{node width: \x1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I try to use message command to access the x1 variable but compile failed:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \message{node width: \x
                           1};
```

Any way I can access it maybe define another global variable?

Comment: You can use `\pgfextra{\xdef\XOneValue{x1}}` before the `;` in the `node` and then that value is available as `\XOneValue`.  The definition of `x1` is only valid within the `\path`, so need to save that value elsewhere.